# How to perform SHA-256 on binary values with Hashlib?

Tags: python, binary, decode, sha256, hashlib

I’m using **Python 2** and am attempting to performing **sha256 on binary values using hashlib.**

I’ve become a bit stuck as I’m quite new to it all but have cobbled together:

> hashlib.sha256('0110100001100101011011000110110001101111’.decode('hex')).hexdigest()

I believe it interprets the string as hex based on substituting the hex value (‘68656c6c6f’) into the above and it returning

> 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824

And comparing to [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5671/how-do-you-perform-double-sha-256-encoding) in which ‘hello’ or ‘68656c6c6f’ is used.

I think the answer lies with the decode component but I can’t find an example for binary only ‘hex’ or ‘utf-8’

**Is anyone able to suggest what needs to be changed so that the function interprets as binary values instead of hex?**

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that does each of the data conversions you are looking for.  These steps can all be combined, but are separated here so you can see each value.

```
import hashlib
import binascii

binstr = '0110100001100101011011000110110001101111'
hexstr = "{0:0>4X}".format(int(binstr,2)) # '68656C6C6F'
data = binascii.a2b_hex(hexstr) # 'hello'
output = hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest()
print output
```

OUTPUT:

2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824